# NodeJS - Problems writing file on Linux - fine on Mac

Tags: linux, node.js

I have a script that writes a file to the file system, here is the code:

```
var filepath = path.join(process.cwd(), '/config/config.js');
var file_contents = 'config stuff';

    fs.writeFile(filepath, file_contents, function(err) {
         if(err) {
              r.errors.push('Could not write config file');
              callback(r);
         } else {
              callback(r)
         }
    });
```

It works fine on my MacBook Pro. I installed NodeJS on an Amazon EC2 server and for some reason it wipes the files contents and doesn't write anything to it.

Any Suggestions ?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the filepath and file_contents?

Comment: I updated the post to inclue the filepath and file_contents.

Comment: Does it work with `var filepath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'config/config.js');` (remove the slash before "config")?

Comment: No err at all ? add console.log(err)

Comment: Do you have write permissions on the path?

Comment: Yes I have 777 permissions on the path and file

Comment: Absolutely no error at all. I tried writing a simple script just to write data to a file and it works fine, the only difference is that I have a fileWatch on the file which will restart the server on a file update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I have Node watching the file for updates. With Mac you can watch a file for updates and still write to it, seems on Amazons EC2 linux AMI, if you are watching a file, you cannot watch and write at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Use `__dirname` instead of `process.cwd()`... `process.cwd()` grabs the "current working directory" (as it's name implies), however, on S3, your code may not be executing from the directory you think. Instead, use the `__dirname` global which is the path of the CURRENT script:

```
var filepath = path.join(__dirname, '/config/config.js');
```

Comment: I tried this and I still get the same result. I get NO errors from the fs.write callback, and it will delete the current contents of the file and not write anything to the file, leaving it blank.